# SharePoint2013 Creating a visual Alert on the Tab of an updated RSS Feed when Multiple Web Parts are Tabbed

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, jquery

On my SP Page, I have 10 RSS feeds organized in Tabs via Javascript. When an RSS Feed is updated, I'd like to have some sort of visual alert for the user **on the tab belonging to the RSS feed that has been updated**.

If possible, I'd like it if the alert only showed on the day of that actual update. Meaning, if the feed was updated on December 22nd, the alert would only show for the duration of December 22nd. I'm still pretty new at SPDev, and I do NOT have InfoPath. Any help would be really appreciated. The code I'm using is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.markrackley.net/scripts/jquery.HillbillyTabs.2013.js"></script> 

<link  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" /> 

<div id="tabsContainer"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    //Put 2 web parts in 2 different tabs
    var webPartTitles = ["Web Part Title 1","Web Part Title 2"];
    HillbillyTabs(webPartTitles);

    //Create a Tab with Two Web Parts, and a second tab with one Web Part
      var webPartTitles = ["Tab Title;#Web Part Title 1;#Web Part Title 2","Web Part Title 3"];
      HillbillyTabs(webPartTitles);

    //Put all web parts (that have visible titles) in current zone into tabs 
    HillbillyTabs();

    });
</script>
```